# Draw route direction overlay on Google Maps or OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, openstreetmap, overlay

I'd like to display the route direction generated from [GraphServer](http://graphserver.github.com/graphserver) on either Google Map or OpenLayers. The result I want is basically identical to how Google Map shows route directions, by highlighting road segments that incorporate the direction. The only difference is that I use GraphServer instead of Google Maps Directions API to generate route direction.

Probably the most trivial approach is to copy over the result from GraphServer, literally point-by-point from every road segments that are part of the route direction, to create polylines or [DirectionsStep](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsStep) in Google Maps. But since this task seems to be something that is used often, I wonder if there is any easier approach. It can be either on Google Maps or OpenLayers, whichever is easier to implement.

Comment: What data format does GraphServer generate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Graphserver you get a geoJson formatted file that you will be able to display with openlayers

Comment: I searched through Graphserver source but couldn't find where it outputs geoJson. Could you please point me to that particular function?

Comment: No, but I can point you to the document I read it http://www.cete-mediterranee.fr/tt13/www/IMG/pdf/sujetcete-graphserver.pdf (in french). A web service is embedded in the app and seems to send a response formatted into geojson. If you're not able to find about that you should maybe ask to the graphserver googlegroup.

Comment: After looking into the code, though Graphserver (particularly its gs_routeserver) produces json output, the output format is not GeoJSON (as it contains richer info regarding directions). However, it can be [configured to output coordinates along with its json output](http://groups.google.com/group/graphserver/browse_thread/thread/62cc8d7e14beae72). Then, it is straightforward enough to create GeoJSON object from the output.

Comment: And for those who're interested, if you want to render GeoJSON on Google Maps, [GeoJSON to Google Maps](https://github.com/JasonSanford/GeoJSON-to-Google-Maps) may come in handy.